# Objective-C Inline Array Declaration With Classes

Tags: objective-c, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to create an array of b2Vec2 arrays using inline declaration. Right now I have...

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    b2Vec2 temp1[] = {
        *new b2Vec2(1,1),
        *new b2Vec2(0,0)
    };

    [array addObject:(id)temp1];

    b2Vec2 temp2[] = {
        *new b2Vec2(1,1),
        *new b2Vec2(0,0)
    };

    [array addObject:(id)temp2];

    b2Vec2 temp3[] = {
        *new b2Vec2(1,1),
        *new b2Vec2(0,0)
    };

    [array addObject:(id)temp3];
```

Is there any way I can get the temp1, temp2, and temp3 declaration inline with the addObject method call? Something like this...

```
[array addObject:<some inline array instantiation>];
[array addObject:<some inline array instantiation>];
[array addObject:<some inline array instantiation>];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. You have to declare the array temp1-3 before you can use it in `[array addObject:]` statement. One thing you can do is creating another function that initializes and returns the array you need.